# Filter node indexes by current domain

Tags: views, search, domain-access

I'm building a D7 site using domain access. What I need now is to make a nodes list for each domain. The list would make use of the Facet API. And the list would only display the nodes on that specific domain.

I used to think adding a NODE INDEX view page, with "avaliable on current domain" filter would do the trick. But then I found there is no "avaliable on current domain" when views is selecting Node Indexes from the database !

What sould be done to restrict the results to current domain?

FYI, the site is using database search, not apache solr

Comment: You may want to check out my sandbox module which does exactly that:
https://drupal.org/sandbox/svendecabooter/2010206

Answer (score 1):

For showing nodes of particular domain on a particular domain, you dont need `avaliable on current domain`. First you have to see, if you are able to see the list of nodes on a particular node without applying the filter on a normal view.

If you cant see the content, then you will have to change some settings by going to link.

```
admin/structure/domain/settings
```

Under Advanced Settings, in Search Settings, check `Search content for the current domain only`

Under Domain Specific Settings >> Domain Settings Behaviour >> `Use the active domain`